# I made a tab panel widget but this is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

The panels are supposed to be switched when they got clicked. The 1st 2 panels are working fine but the other two are not working they just hide the active tab and do not become active when they got clicked also after getting clicked on panel 3 and 4 the first 2 panels also do not work.

```
<head>
    <title>Tab Panel Widget</title>

    <script src = "jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

    <style>

        .tab-panels ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .tab-panels ul li.active {
            background: #666;
        }

        .tab-panels ul li {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #999;
            padding: 3px 10px;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 200;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tab-panels ul li:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background: #666;
        }

        .tab-panels .panel {
            display: none;
            background: #c9c9c9;
            padding: 30px;
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }

        .tab-panels .panel.active {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class = "tab-panels">

        <ul class = "tabs">
            <li rel = "panel1" class = "active">panel1</li>
            <li rel = "panel2">panel2</li>
            <li rel = "panel3">panel3</li>
            <li rel = "panel4">panel4</li>
        </ul>

        <div id = "panel1" class = "panel active"">
        content1<br>
        content1<br>
        content1<br>
        content1<br>
        content1<br>
        </div>

        <div id = "panel2" class = "panel">
        content2<br>
        content2<br>
        content2<br>
        content2<br>
        content2<br>
        </div>

        <div id = "panel1" class = "panel">
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        </div>

        <div id = "panel1" class = "panel">
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".tab-panels .tabs li").on("click", function(){
                $(".tab-panels .tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                var panelToShow = $(this).attr("rel");
                $(".tab-panels .panel.active").slideUp(300, function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                    $("#"+panelToShow).slideDown(300, function(){
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can't use the same id = "panel1" in HTML.

Comment: thanks just a little mistake ...

Comment: Add an HTML validator to your toolbox: https://validator.w3.org/  it could save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

Change panel 3 and panel 4

change panel -1 to panel 3 for third div secction and panel-1 to panel 4 for the fourth div section

```
<div id = "panel3" class = "panel">
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        content3<br>
        </div>

        <div id = "panel4" class = "panel">
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        content4<br>
        </div>

    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJzEzm

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "panel1" class = "panel active"">
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    </div>
```

you should delete the second " symbol after the active class. the code should be like that

```
<div id = "panel1" class = "panel active">
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    content1<br>
    </div>
```

and you should use different id for each one.